# how to get this element with jsoup in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup

i want to get return string of this tag, but i cannot get it work.

**html is:**

```
<td><a href="Onepunch-Man/05/2"><img src="mangas/Onepunch-Man/05/01.jpg" alt="Komik Onepunch-Man chapter 05 gambar 1 Bahasa Indonesia" width="1000" height="949" class="picture" /></a></td>

<select name="page" onchange="change_page('Onepunch-Man', '05', this.value)"><option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select> of 9 <a href="Onepunch-Man/05/2"><img src="themes/default/next.png" alt="Gambar Berikutnya" title="Next Page" /></a></span>
</div> //

<div id="komentar">
<div class="isikomentar">
<center><div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=164624353679735#&amp;xfbml=1">     
</script>
<fb:comments href="http://www.pecintakomik.com/manga/Onepunch-Man/05" migrated=1 num_posts="5" width="800">
</fb:comments>
</center>

</div>
</div>
```

i have java class that parse that element and store on sqllite db.

**my program** to get page url and image url is:

```
private List<String> parseHtmlToPageUrls(String unparsedHtml) {

    int beginIndex = unparsedHtml.indexOf("<select name=\"page\">");
    int endIndex = unparsedHtml.indexOf("</select>", beginIndex);
    String trimmedHtml = unparsedHtml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);

    Document parsedDocument = Jsoup.parse(trimmedHtml);

    List<String> pageUrlList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Elements testElement = parsedDocument.getElementsByTag("fb:comments");

    Elements pageUrlElements = parsedDocument.getElementsByTag("option");

    for (Element pageUrlElement : pageUrlElements) {
        pageUrlList.add(testElement.attr("href") +"/"+ pageUrlElement.attr("value"));
    }
    return pageUrlList;
}

private String parseHtmlToImageUrl(String unparsedHtml) {

    Document parsedDocument = Jsoup.parse(unparsedHtml);

    Element imageElement = parsedDocument.select("img.picture").first();

    return "http://www.pecintakomik.com/manga/" + imageElement.attr("src");
}
```

please help me anyone, is there wrong in my tag?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:  `fb|comments` instead of:  `fb:comments`

```
 private static List<String> parseHtmlToPageUrls(String unparsedHtml) {

    Document parsedDocument = Jsoup.parse(unparsedHtml);
    List<String> pageUrlList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Element testElement = parsedDocument.select("fb|comments").first();
    Elements pageUrlElements = parsedDocument.getElementsByTag("option");

    for (Element pageUrlElement : pageUrlElements) {
        pageUrlList.add(testElement.attr("href") +"/"+ pageUrlElement.attr("value"));
    }
    return pageUrlList;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer @martic , can i write   `int beginIndex = unparsedHtml.indexOf("<select name=\"page\">");` ? because its say StringIndexOutOfBoundsException at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength at line `String trimmedHtml = unparsedHtml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);`

Comment: Use `Elements pageUrlElements = parsedDocument.select("select[name=page] option");` instead of `int beginIndex = unparsedHtml.indexOf(...`.